# What are the Major Meditation Traditions / Masters in Laos / Cambodia / Vietnam?

Tags: meditation-classification, practice

What are the Major Meditation Traditions / Masters in Laos / Cambodia /  Vietnam? Does Cambodia prominent meditation lineages which originated in Laos / Cambodia /  Vietnam? What are the lineages originating elsewhere coming to Laos / Cambodia /  Vietnam? Do they have variation from practiced elsewhere?

Answer (score 4):

Valued Upasaka Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena

Atma can only tell you about Cambodia. Meditation is a very death matter. There are 3 main streams, currently:

1. One and most popular and growing: Goenka. A second center is currently in building in Central Cambodia.
2. The secound most dominate lineage is that of But Sovung, originated from Acharn Sujin, a Thai Upasika (also teacher of Upasika Nina Van Gorkum), which avoids in somehow everything that could cause Jhana and is merely a dry Adhidhamma tradition ([Dhamma in Cambodia](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/vangorkom/dhammacambo_en.html)), but most successful in manners of gaining.
3. The "formal" branch of "[Vipassana Dhura Buddhist Meditation Center](http://www.cambodiavipassanacenter.com/)" with the most public and governmental support, focusing more on Jhana.

Under 1.000 monks, you would find 10 who have learned meditation a little and 1 who regular practice it. The same with laypeople. Such as daily practice is merely unknown and people are much to busy so that they would scarify time. So if, there are mainly such as retreats or courses here and there, events. In every region one finds on this or that hill such as a meditation guru, mostly focusing on samadhi. The forest Tradition is extincted. Atma came across some disciples of older lineages, but those Monks (mostly 50+) mostly have stopped to teach or are busy to build Meditation Building first.

There is one monastery in Siam Reap, which is sad to focus on meditation. Atma had met some monks from there but did not personally came there till today.

All in all it holds true, if there is no Sila, there is no foundation for samadhi. Maybe Atma is able to share more contacts and hints.